# Ember + Ember Data: How to rollback a record after calling deleteRecord()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an `Em.ArrayController` with a bunch of records in it. They are all controlled by an `itemController`.

```
App.ColorsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'color', 
  actions: {
    discardChanges: function() {
      this.get('content').forEach(function(color) { color.rollback(); }
      // also tried an arrayComputed property like this:
      // deletedRecords: Em.computed.filterBy('content', 'isDeleted', true);
    }
  }
});
```

If I call `deleteRecord()` on one of the models (from an action in the itemController, the model is removed from the `model` of the `ArrayController`.

```
App.ColorController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    deleteColor: function() {
      // does not send a `DELETE` request, only
      // changes the state of the record
      this.get('content').deleteRecord();
    }
  } 
});
```

Remember that `deleteRecord` doesn't submit a network request, it merely transitions the state of the object to `deleted.uncommitted`.

Do I need to manually retain some sort of handle on this object after deleting it? Or is there some way for the ArrayController to access items in this state.

I've attempted to filter the content of the ArrayController by `isDeleted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array controller is being backed by a filter.  Filters are active, in that they automatically add/remove records as the store has active records added/removed.  (fyi, `find('foo')` returns the `all` filter).

You can copy the contents to a non active collection/array which won't automagically add/remove the models (you will have to do everything manually).  The easiest place would be to override the `setupController` and add a property onto your controller, which can be accessed in your template.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    this.store.find('foo');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('staticFoos', model.toArray());
  }
});
```

Comment: Sweet. I was afraid I would not be able to use array computed properties on Em.Array() if I converted `DS.RecordArray` to a regular array, but looks like it still works.

Comment: .@kingpin2k how would I do this if the model is set by `{{render}}` instead of the model hook in a route? I'm tempted to use `init`, but the model won't be loaded on init, so it will copy a blank array.